# htaccess rewrite rule not working with magento

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

This is the rewrite rule does not working in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/magento/resultados-busqueda/ 
RewriteRule resultados-busqueda/(.*) /magento/index.php/catalogsearch/result/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

If I add [R] flag, it's work fine, but without [R] does not work.

Please help!!

Sorry for my english.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below .htaccess snippet in your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/magento/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /magento

RewriteRule ^resultados-busqueda/([^/]+)/?$ /magento/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [QSA,P,NC]
```

Comment: Is Magento installed under `/magento` folder?

Comment: Yes, Magento is installed under /magento folder

Comment: `still not working` doesn't give any info to help you? What URI did u try in browser? What is your latest .htaccess? (paste in question) and finally what error you got?

Comment: I need some info about the error you're getting like what URI did you try to open in browser and what error did you see?

Comment: this url show me error 404:http://domain.com/magento/resultados-busqueda/pantalon

Comment: In your .htaccess move my suggested `RewriteRule` line just below `RewriteBase /magento` line.

Comment: Nothing, continue not working and show me the same error 404 with the same url. I think it is due to something magento configuration which does not allow rewrite urls.

Comment: I believe your rule is working fine but your target URI might have some issues. Can you check if `http://domain.com/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/result/pantalon` is opening the page fine for you?

Comment: Yes I did, and it is work perfectly, for this reason I think it is due to magento condiguration.

Comment: Ok good, can you try this rule instead `RewriteRule ^resultados-busqueda/(.*)$ /magento/index.php/catalogsearch/result/$1 [R,L,NC]` Note extra `R` in flags.

Comment: This does not work, is what I said in the question that if I add [R] flag its work if not its not work. I do not know what can I do..

Comment: See my edited answer now. (You need to have mod_proxy enabled in your apache).

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that the new Apache version has changed in some way, if you are using apache 2.4, I suggest you to change your `etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file (you'll need root permission) as follows:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It works ;)

Answer (score 0):

URI domain/magento/resultados-busqueda/pantalones and show error 404.
This my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /magento

RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^resultados-busqueda/(.*)$ /magento/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```